# Bound on eigenvalues of a certain symmetric DPR1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a set of real numbers $a_1, \dots, a_d$, define:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_1 a_2  & \dots & a_1 a_n  \\
a_2 a_1  & 0 & \dots & a_2 a_n  \\
\vdots & & \ddots &  \vdots \\
a_n a_1  & \dots & a_n a_{n-1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I would like to obtain (the tightest possible) bound on the eigenvalues of $A$. I need both a lower and an upper bound.

I know it can be expressed as a DPR1, diagonal plus rank-one, matrix, and there are *algorithms* for finding eigenvalues of such matrices. But I wasn't able to find a bound in terms of the numbers $a_1$, ..., $a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One set of inequalities we can get is [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory). Let $\lambda_1(D)\geq \cdots \geq \lambda_d(D)$ denote the eigenvalues (i.e. diagonal entries) of the diagonal matrix $D = -\operatorname{diag}(a_1^2,\dots,a_n^2)$. Let $R$ denote the rank-1 matrix with entries $r_{ij} = a_ia_j$, so that $A = D + R$. For each $i = 1,\dots,n$, we have the upper bound
$$
\lambda_i(A) \leq \lambda_i(D) + \lambda_1(R) = \lambda_i(D) + \|a\|^2, 
$$
where $a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)$ so that $\|a\|^2 = a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2$. We also have the "interlacing" inequalities
$$
\lambda_1(A) \geq \lambda_1(D) \geq \lambda_2(A) \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_{n-1}(D) \geq \lambda_{n}(D + A) \geq \lambda_n(D).
$$

Comment: What a beautiful answer!

Comment: So in fact, if I want a global value on all eigenvalues, an upper bound is $\max_i a_i^2 + \|a\|^2$, and a lower-bound is $-\max_i a_i^2$, right?

Comment: @AlexShtof Almost. The upper bound that you get is $\|a\|^2 - \max_i a_i^2$. Otherwise, that's correct.